# IOS App CoreData is reset when app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

On the device when the application is running and an error occurs, the application is closed and back to start, and sometimes the data I saved in `CoreData` has been removed. I am currently using `MagicalRecord (2.2)` to `CoreData`

An example of how I'm using `CoreData` with `MagicalRecord`:

```
- (void)deletePlaylistData:(NSDictionary *)playlist {

   PlaylistOffline *object = [PlaylistOffline MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:playlist[@"id"]];

   if (object) {

      [object MR_deleteEntity];
      [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

   } else {
       NSLog(@"Error al eliminar Playlist");
   }
}
```

*I'm new to Objective-C and I hope your help thanks, Excuse my English by Google translator*

Comment: Ask about and fix the crash. If you haven't saved before the crash then the data will be lost.

Comment: The data already stored in CoreData, but the error causes all previously saved are deleted

Comment: In any event, fix the crash. Then, test to ensure your app works properly.

Comment: It sounds like the save is causing the crash? If you specifically save the context that is aware of your persistent store coordinator than it will be persisted if the crash occurs after. It really sounds like the crash is occurring before the save finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No crash will cause data to be deleted from disk.  There is simply no connection between the two.

If you are creating objects but not saving them via `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` then they are not being written to disk.

If you are using `UIManagedDocument`, stop. Use the template provided Core Data stack from Apple.

But, in the end, do what @Wain suggested.  Fix the crash.

If you are getting a crash as part of the save, then post the crash log so we can assist with that.

Comment: if you're probably right, did not understand the connection between CodeData and error, Thanks, now I have more clear solution